# OneNote class notebook group principal objects example?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

I've been developing an app using OneNote SDK specifically OneNote Class Notebooks feature.

Can somebody give me an example of how to invite a "Group" principal objects as a student?

In this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-classnotebook) I can only find an example for "Person" principal object.

Assume that I have created an Office 365 Group (Unified Group) on my tenant, is it possible to invite that group to the class notebook as a student?

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/how-to/onenote-classnotebook#add-students-and-teachers):

> Teachers and students are represented by principal objects, which contain the following properties:
>
> `id` -    The Office 365 user principal name. See the Azure AD Graph API documentation to learn more about users and groups.
>
> `principalType` - `Person` or `Group`

Based on this, you should be able to add the Group using

```
{
    "id": "alias@tenant",
    "principalType": "Group"
}
```